# Optimize $f(x,y) = \sqrt{3} x + y$ over the upper half of a circle.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined as follows $$ D =
>  \bigr\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq y \leq\sqrt{1-x^2}\bigl\} $$
>   The problem is to find the maximum and minimum of the function
>   $$f(x,y) = \sqrt{3}x + y$$ for $x,y \in D$.

I tried to let $k = \sqrt{3}x + y$ so that $y = k - \sqrt{3}x$ and then to solve

$$k - \sqrt{3} x = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

However, this lead to some quite messy calculations. Is there an easier way?

Comment: This can be done easily with Lagrange Multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

How about using angles, $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = (x,y)$  ?
$$g(\theta) = \sqrt3\cos\theta + \sin\theta$$

$$g'(\theta) = -\sqrt3\sin\theta + \cos\theta$$

For maximum, solve for $g'(\theta)=0$:
$$\sqrt3\sin\theta = \cos\theta$$
$$\tan\theta = {1 \over \sqrt3} = \tan({\pi \over 6})$$

$$max(f(x,y)) = \large g({\pi \over 6}) = \sqrt3\times({\sqrt3 \over 2}) + {1\over2} = 2$$
$$min(f(x,y)) = f(-1,0) = -\sqrt3$$

---

Another way, without doing differentiation

$$g(\theta)=\sqrt3\cos\theta + \sin\theta = 2 \cos(\theta-{\pi\over6})$$

$$max(f(x,y)) = max(g(\theta)) = 2$$

Answer (score 1):

The objective function is linear, so the extrema occur at the corner points of the domain. It follows that the maximum value is $\sqrt 3,$ and the minimum $-\sqrt 3.$

Comment: What do you mean by the corner points? Are they $(\pm 1,0)$ only? The theorem says that the extrema are attained at the extreme points which are not only corners but also the "upper" semicircle.

Comment: indeed, the other answer demonstrates that $2$, which is $>\sqrt3$, is attained

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From what you have,

$$k - \sqrt{3} x = \sqrt{1-x^2}$$

arrange the equation in the standard form

$$4x^2-2\sqrt 3 kx + k^2-1=0$$

Note that $k$ given by the line equation $k=\sqrt 3 x+y$ is the $y$-intercept of the line. $k$ takes the maximum value when it is tangential to the circle from above, that is, the discriminate of the above equation is zero,

$$b^2-4ac = 12k^2-16(k^2-1)=0$$

Thus, the maximum value of $k$ is

$$k_{max} = 2$$

On the other hand, the $y$-intercept $k$ takes the minimum value if the line touches the far-left point $(-1,0)$ on the circle from below, i.e.

$$k_{min}=\sqrt 3(-1)+0=-\sqrt 3$$

Comment: Is k = √(3)*x + √ (1-x^2), a curve ? How is k the y-intercept of the line ?  I think the answer *assumed* there is only 1 local maximum, thus max(k) when quadratic only gives 1 (repeated) root for x.  In other words, discriminant = 0.

Comment: @albertchan:    $k$ is the $y$-intercept of the line $k=\sqrt3x+y$

Comment: Thanks.  We can use geometry too! Let P is the tangent intercept, slope(OP)=1/√ 3 → θ =30° , kmax = 1/sin(θ) = 2